# How to prove $a^n < n!$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, and $n! \leq n^n$ for all $n$, by induction?

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

I have a couple things I want to prove. I'm pretty sure a proof by induction is the best route for these.

---

First, I need to show that $5^n < n!$ from some $n_{0} > 0$. I'm choosing $n_{0} = 12$ since that's the smallest positive integer where $n! > 5^n$.

So: $P(k) : 5^k < k!$

1. Show $P(12)$: $5^{12} < 12!$
2. Assume $P(k)$, show $P(k+1)$:

$P(k+1):$

$5^{(k+1)} \leq (k+1)!$

$5*5^k \leq (k+1)*k!$

This is where I'm stuck. Since our previous assumption was that $5^k \leq k!$, couldn't we conclude the proof by showing:
$5 \leq (k+1)$ for $n \geq 12$?

---

The second one is:

$P(k): n! \leq n^n$

1. Show $P(1)$: $1 \leq 1$
2. Assume $P(k)$, show $P(k+1)$:

$P (k+1):$

$(n+1)! \leq {n+1}^{n+1}$

$(n+1)*n! \leq {(n+1)} *{(n+1)}^{n}$

If we cancel out the common factor (we can do that, right?) $(n+1)$ we get:

$n! \leq (n+1)^n$ which is true for $n \geq1$.

Therefore, $n! \leq n^n$ for $n \geq 1 $

---

So in conclusion, I'm wondering if these proofs are sufficient (and correct). I kinda feel like I'm missing something in the last few steps - that it's "turtles all the way down"

Answer (score 9):

**HINT** $\ $ Rewrite them as products so to make the induction completely trivial.

Namely $\quad\quad\displaystyle  \frac{n^n}{n\:!}\ =\ \ \: \frac{n}1\ \ \ \frac{n}2\: \ \ \frac{n}3\ \:\cdots\ \frac{n}n\ \ge\ 1\ \ $ since each factor is $\:\ge 1$

$\quad$ and $\rm\quad\quad\displaystyle\ \frac{n\:!}{5^n}\ =\ \frac{12\:!}{5^{12}}\ \frac{13}{5}\ \frac{14}5\ \cdots\ \frac{n}5\ >\ 1\ \ $ since each factor is $\:  > 1$

Now you need only inductively prove the lemma that a product is $\ge 1\:$ or $> 1\:$ if each factor is - which is completely trivial. Many inductive proofs can be similarly drastically simplified by conceptual preprocessing. Here we've effectively employed **multiplicative telescopy** to reduce generally intractable exponential inequalities to tractable polynomial inequalities. $\: $ This is a powerful technique with widespread applications. See also the analogous case of [**additive telescopy**](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6814) and the fundamental theorem of difference calculus.

Answer (score 5):

Your first proof is correct.  (If $a\le c$ and $b\le d$ and they're all positive, then $ab\le cd$.)  Your second one needs just a tiny bit more.  How do we know that $n!\le (n+1)^n$?  It follows from your inductive hypothesis, but it's not completely trivial.

As a general tip, try not to work your proofs backwards.  When you're trying to prove that $P(k)\Rightarrow P(k+1)$, you start out by stating $P(k+1)$ and then deriving a true statement.  It works here because pretty much everything you're doing is reversible (dividing by $k+1$ vs. multiplying), but in later life, this might no longer be true and so it's a good practice to start now.

Otherwise, good work!