# The sum of three consecutive cubes numbers produces 9 multiple

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, induction, divisibility, natural-numbers

I want to prove that $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3$ is always a $9$ multiple

I used induction by the way.

I reach this expression:  $(n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 + (n+3)^3$

But is a lot of time to calculate each three terms, so could you help me to achieve the induction formula

Thanks in advance

Comment: There are many ways to get to this result, some more efficient than others. At the less efficient end, try *expanding* the expression rather than simplifying it. $n^3 + (n + 1)^3 + (n + 2)^3$ expands to $3n^3 + 9n^2 + 15n + 9$. Chuck $9n^2 + 9$ to leave us with $3n^3 + 15n$. If $n \equiv 1 \mod 9$, then $3n^3 + 15n \equiv 3 + 6 \mod 9$. If $n \equiv 2 \mod 9$, then $3n^3 + 15n \equiv 6 + 3$. And so on and so forth.

Comment: Not to nitpick, but "equations" have equals signs. I don't see an equation anywhere in your question.

Comment: @LuisArmando You can edit your own questions by clicking on the edit link

Comment: Thanks @TimSeguine, **equation** has been changed to **expression**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As an alternative to induction, we take any $3$ consecutive cubes as follows:

$$(n-1)^3 + n^3 + (n+1)^3$$
$$= 3n^3  + 6n$$
$$=3n(n^2 +2)$$
Notice that

$$\begin{align}n(n^2 + 2) &\equiv n(n^2-1)\pmod 3 \\&\equiv (n-1)(n)(n+1)\pmod 3 \end{align}$$

Since either one of $(n-1),n$ or $(n+1)$ must be divisible by $3$, it follows that$3|n(n^2+2)$. This implies that $3\cdot3=9$ divides $3n(n^2 +2)$.

Answer (score 8):

The difference from one step to the next is $(n+3)^3-n^3$, which has just a few terms.

Comment: I calculated the result and I have:

$3n^3$+$18n^2$+ $42n$+ $36$.  How can I prove the induction method?

Comment: For the inductive step, you just need $(n+3)^3-n^3=9n^2+27n+27$.  Since the value at $n=0$ is a multiple of 9, and the difference at each stage is a multiple of 9,...

Answer (score 6):

**Hint** $\ (n\!-\!1)^3\! + n^3\! + (n\!+\!1)^3\! -9n = 3\underbrace{(n\!-\!1)n(n\!+\!1)}_{\large \rm divisible\ by\ 3}\,$ since they've same roots and lead coef.

Answer (score 5):

There is one really elegant and simple way of proving this by means of induction. 
It goes as following:

Define the problem as: $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 = 9\lambda$

Test for $n=1$; $1^3+2^3+3^3=9\lambda$; $36=4*9$

Assume that for some $n \in N$ -> $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 = 9\lambda$

Test for $n+1$

$
 (n+1)^3+(n+2)^3+(n+3)^3 = 9\lambda
$

$
(n+1)^3+(n+2)^3+(n+3)(n^2+6n+9)=9\lambda
$
$(n+1)^3+(n+2)^3+n^3+9n^2+27n+27$

According to our assumption $n^3+(n+1)^3+(n+2)^3$ is divisible by 9 so we can put
$9k$ instead giving us:

$9k + 9n^2+27n+27 = 9(k+n^2+3n+3) = \lambda9$

$Q.E.D$

Answer (score 2):

Using induction: Check that $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3$ is a multiple of 9 when n = 0.

Next you know that $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3$ is a multiple of 9 and want to show that $(n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3 + (n+3)^3$ is a multiple of 9. Well, what's the difference between these two sums?

The bad thing is that it's a lot of time for me to calculate the difference. The good thing is that it's your problem, so don't be lazy and calculate the difference. The solution actually ends up very simple.

Answer (score 2):

Why not let MMA do the proof?

```
In[159]:= f[m_] := Sum[k^3, {k, m, m + 2}]

In[161]:= Simplify[Mod[f[m], 9], Element[m, Integers]]

Out[161]= 0
```

Regards,
Wolfgang

Comment: Interesting, but the OP is trying to determine what the proof is, not convince him/herself that the assertion is true.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an approach using the same basic thinking as modular arithmetic, without actually using modular arithmetic. Any three consecutive numbers will feature one number which  is a multiple of $3$ (call it $3a$), one number $1$ greater than a multiple of $3$ (call it $3b+1$), and one number which is $1$ smaller than a multiple of $3$ (call it $3c-1$). Depending on the particular value of the first of the consecutive numbers, one or more of $a,b,c$ may be the same, but we don't need to rely on that here. We just sum the cubes of the three numbers.

$(3a)^3+(3b+1)^3+(3c-1)^3=27a^3+27b^3+27b^2+9b+1+27c^3-27c^2+9c-1$.

Note that on the RHS, the $1$ and $-1$ cancel, so the remaining terms reduce to:

$9(3a^3+3b^3+3b^2+b+3c^3-3c^2+c)$, which has an explicit factor of $9$. QED