# Does it make sense to claim that something cannot be proven without induction?

Tags: logic, induction, proof-theory

Often we have questions on this site which ask for a proof of some result *without induction*.<sup>1</sup> It seems that when such a question is posted, it is quite well-understood what is meant by proof avoiding induction.<sup>2</sup> But can the meaning of this phrase be precise?

> - Is it possible to define *formally* what do "proof without induction" and "proof using induction" mean?

For example, I would suspect that if the claim contains some object defined by induction, then we would expect that the proof uses induction, too. (Perhaps in some non-obvious way.) In the other words, if we want induction-free proof, we should have induction-free formulation of the theorem. (Although I do not claim that this intuition is correct - as you can see from this question, I cannot give even reasonable formalization of this.)

Examples of claims which are typically shown by induction and which involve objects defined by induction could be:<sup>3</sup>

- $\sum_{k=1}^n k = \frac{n(n+1)}2$ (We have several posts about this sum, for example [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2260/proof-for-formula-for-sum-of-sequence-123-ldotsn).)
- If $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are elements of a finite abelian group $G=\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}$ (where $|G|=n$, i.e. no element is listed twice), then $(a_1a_2\dots a_n)^2$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474214/product-of-elements-of-a-finite-abelian-group)

Of course, induction can also be used in proofs where inductive (recursive) definitions are not used in the formulation of the result.<sup>4</sup>

> - If we have some formalization of the distinction between proofs with/without induction, is it possible to prove about some results that induction cannot be avoided in the proof?
> - What are some examples of results for which it is proven that any proof will need induction. (For some reasonable meaning of the phrase "need induction".)

Perhaps I could imagine something like this when working with [Peano axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms). We could simply omit the induction axiom and ask whether there is a proof using the remaining axioms. (Or whether there is a model in which the claim fails.) However, in this way we restrict ourselves to claims about natural numbers. Moreover, if we want to omit induction axioms, we would have problems already with formulating results which use recursive definitions. (The fact that recursive definitions are possible in Peano Arithmetic is proved using this axiom. Some authors calls this result [Recursion Theorem](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22peano+axioms%22+%22recursion+theorem%22).)

The question becomes more complicated if we move beyond natural numbers. For example, if we are working in ZFC, then there is not an easy way out by just saying: "Let us omit the axiom about induction."

---

<sup>1</sup>You can [find many such questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=without+induction). Some of the most popular examples (base on the number of views and score) could be [Proving the identity $\sum_{k=1}^n {k^3} = \big(\sum_{k=1}^n k\big)^2$ without induction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61482/proving-the-identity-sum-k-1n-k3-big-sum-k-1n-k-big2-without-i)

<sup>2</sup>I do not remember seeing some lengthy argument about whether some proof involves induction or not. Just compare that with the [guess the next number](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/924/guess-the-next-number-guess-the-relation-etc) type of questions. Situation is somewhat similar in that we often intuitively can see whether some answer is correct (or at least reasonable) or not; whether it was the solution intended by the creator of the problem. But such questions almost immediately get the response: "Any number can be an answer. Just take Lagrange interpolation."

<sup>3</sup>Here $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k$ is defined inductively by $S_{n+1}=S_n+(n+1)$. Similarly, we have inductive definition for $a_1a_2\dots a_n$. I think that the well-know proofs use induction in some hidden way. For example, the proof based on $2S_n=(1+\dots+n)+(n+\dots+1)=\underset{\text{$n$-times}}{\underbrace{(n+1)+\dots+(n+1)}}$ used commutativity several times. Similarly in the proof that product of all elements of abelian groups we would use commutativity. If by commutativity we mean that the product of $n$ elements gives the same result when reordered in any way, the formal proof of this fact would be based on induction.

<sup>4</sup>One example I was able to find quickly: [Simple Proof by induction: $9$ divides $n^3 + (n+1)^3 + (n+2)^3$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6805/simple-proof-by-induction-9-divides-n3-n13-n23) But I cannot at the moment think of an example where it would be difficult to give a proof without induction.

Comment: I think this might be related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200105/avoiding-proof-by-induction. (Actually, is this not a duplicate?)

Comment: I wrote *partial answer* because I also asked what happens beyond PA. But it is possible that I see a difference simply because I misunderstood that answer (I will certainly need some time to digest it.) And maybe asking this question outside PA or some similar system is completely nonsensical. I will let the community decide whether they are duplicates.

Comment: Repost of my older comment (which was deleted for some reason...?): This was closed as a duplicate of the question [Avoiding proof by induction](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1200105/avoiding-proof-by-induction). I think that they are somewhat different. My question is more about formalization of the notion of "proof without induction". The other question accepts "simple proofs" and asks about "natural theorems". Of course, I agree that the questions are close to each other and Noah's answer to that question probably could be considered at least partial answer to this question, too.