# Prove by induction that $n! > n^2$

Tags: inequality, induction, factorial

How does one prove by induction that

$n! > n^2$

for $n \geq 4$

Comment: This is not true when n=1

Comment: How does one prove anything by induction?  Can you say which part of the general method is problematic in this case?

Comment: Should there be some restriction on the value of $n$, because the statement is false for $n = 1, 2, 3$?

Comment: The OP probably intended for $n \geq 4$.

Comment: @cardinal yes, of course!

Comment: I edited it sorry it deserved a -1....

Comment: Related question: [How to prove $a^n < n!$ for all $n$ sufficiently large, and $n! \leq n^n$ for all $n$, by induction?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6581/how-to-prove-an-n-for-all-n-sufficiently-large-and-n-leq-nn-for-al)

Comment: See also: [Prove by induction that $n^2<n!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1140396/prove-by-induction-that-n2n) and [Hint in Proving that $n^2\le n!$](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/764808/hint-in-proving-that-n2-le-n)

Answer (score 3):

To prove that this inequality holds for $n \geq 4$, first we verify the base case, which is trivial, as $24 >16$.

Now assume for some $k$ that $k! > k^2$. Then $(k+1)! > (k+1)k^2 = k^3+k^2 > (k+1)^2$. We can verify the right hand inequality, as this implies that $k^2 > k+1 \implies k^2-k-1>0$, which is clearly true for $k \geq 4$; the inductive step has thus been proven and we're done.

Comment: did you mean $k^3-k-1>0$?

Comment: I meant $k^2-k-1>0$; I got that expression by dividing the right hand inequality by $k+1$.

Comment: ahh sorry my bad

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see the other post answered when searching

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:*

If $n! > n^2$ holds, can you show that 
$$ (n+1)! = n! (n+1) > (n+1)^2 = n^2 +2 n+1?$$